# Clustered Scheduled Task

Tags: powershell

i try to regist a new ClusteredScheduledTask on windows server 2012 with powershell. but the task can't set the RepetitionInterval and RepetitionDuration properly.

```
$T = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At 08:10AM -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Hours 1) -RepetitionDuration (New-TimeSpan -Hours 12)
```

Task Scheduler ui can see Triggers only execute once on 08:10 but no RepetitionInterval and RepetitionDuration.

can you tell me what went wrong? thanks.
Joe

Comment: Works for me. Can you share the full code?

Comment: $A = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Robocopy_backup.bat"
$T = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At 08:10AM -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Hours 1) -RepetitionDuration (New-TimeSpan -Hours 12)
Register-ClusteredScheduledTask –Cluster clsAP –TaskName Robocopyto100 –TaskType ResourceSpecific –Resource Data –Action $A –Trigger $T -Description "Robocopy to 100"

Comment: never mind, i reinstall os, it works again!